# Weird $_GET behaviour

Tags: php, mysql, get

Hi im trying to fix a bug with my script. The problem is my get query still works with extra letters.

So, `edit.php?id=1` works and so does `edit.php?id=1hello` (obviously it shouldnt). Whats happening?

```
$idtoedit = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);

//Check if ID exists
$doesidexist = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM Data WHERE `id` = \"$idtoedit\"");
if (mysql_num_rows($doesidexist) == 0) {
    die("<div class=\"alert alert-error\"><h4 class=\"alert-heading\">Error</h4><p>ID does not exist.</p><p><a class=\"btn btn-danger\" href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">Go Back</a></p></div></div></body></html>");
 }
```

Comment: `obviously it wouldn't` - why not?

Comment: I remember having read something lately, that IDs shouldn't start by an number, nor recommended. As to the "why", that I don't know. I only remember having read something to that affect, the answer coming from a 38k member.

Comment: Only strings need to be escaped (hence "mysql_real_escape_string" and not "mysql_real_escape_anything"). For numerical values you should better use `$idtoedit = intval($_GET['id']);`, which also helps understand the behaviour you're asking about.

Comment: You should use mysqli_* functions. mysql_* is deprecated.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers if any helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of MySQL's "anything goes" handling of input, when converting strings to numbers.

The SQL query you build pass the input in as a string (the `"`s around it) so mysql will try to convert it to a number, if the column on the left hand side of the `=` has a number type (the `id` column in your example).

Check [this section of the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/type-conversion.html) for further information.

Comment: +1 Good explanation :) I always use type casting so this was new to me! :)

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_real_escape_string` only "cleans" the variable so it's safe to use in the query, however it doesn't cast it into an integer and it's not supposed to. You can use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to and parameterized queries to do it, otherwise you have to manually cast it yourself i.e.

```
$idtoedit = (int) mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
```

[PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) example:

```
$sth = $pdoObject->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM Data WHERE `id` = ?');
$sth->bindParam(1, $_GET["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->execute();
```

Edit:
Haven't really answered your question so to clarify:
Just like complex857 said, MySQL tries to convert it based on the column type, therefore casting `1hello` results in an integer value of 1.